# Getting associated values from Python dictionary that is using lists

Tags: python, django

Ok, so I am working on an application that can go through a number of different database objects, compare the string and return the associated id, first name and last name. I currently have it to where I am building a list of tuples and then populating a dictionary with the key and values(using a list). What I want to do next is find the Max percentage and then return the associated fist and last name from the dictionary. I know the description is a little confusing so please look at the below examples and code:

```
# My Dictionary: 
    {'percent': [51.9, 52.3, 81.8, 21.0], 'first_name': ['Bob', 'Bill', 'Matt', 'John'], 'last_name': ['Smith', 'Allen', 'Naran', 'Jacobs']}

# I would want this to be returned:
    percent = 81.8 (Max percentage match)
    first_name = 'Matt' (First name associated with the max percentage match)
    last_name = 'Naran' (Last name associated with the max percentage match)

# Code so Far:
    compare_list = []
    compare_dict = {}

# Builds my list of Tuples
    compare_list.append(tuple(("percent", percentage)))
    compare_list.append(tuple(("first_name", first_name)))
    compare_list.append(tuple(("last_name", last_name)))

# Builds my Dictionary
    for x, y in compare_list:
        compare_dict.setdefault(x, []).append(y)
```

Not sure where to go to return the first and last name associated with the Max percentage.

I really appreciate any and all help that you provide!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you:

```
data = {'percent': [51.9, 52.3, 81.8, 21.0], 'first_name': ['Bob', 'Bill', 'Matt', 'John'], 'last_name': ['Smith', 'Allen', 'Naran', 'Jacobs']}


percentage_list = data['percent']
percentage = max(percentage_list)
max_index = percentage_list.index(percentage)

first_name = data['first_name'][max_index]
last_name = data['last_name'][max_index]


# Code so Far:
compare_list = []
compare_dict = {}

# Builds my list of Tuples
compare_list.append(tuple(("percent", percentage)))
compare_list.append(tuple(("first_name", first_name)))
compare_list.append(tuple(("last_name", last_name)))

# Builds my Dictionary
for x, y in compare_list:
    compare_dict.setdefault(x, []).append(y)

print compare_dict
```

Comment: Perfect!! That did exactly what I was looking for